# Segmentation Fault whenever using vector<>

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, iostream

```
int main()

{

    int n;

    cin >> n;


    char* temp_char;
    vector<string> arr; 


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

    {

        cin >> temp_char;

    }





    return 0;

}
```

Hi, whenever I have `vector<string> arr;` in this program, no matter I actually use this variable arr or not, after the first cin in the first forloop, I receive segmentation fault, don't know why is this happening? I do need to use `vector<string>` in the later programming.
I'm compiling with g++ under Ubuntu, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try using `string temp_str` instead, it'll make things much easier.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm not sure in your code, but I think you have to use 
    char temp_char
insted of
    char* temp_char
or at least allocate some memory to temp_char:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{  
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    char* temp_char = new char[100];
    std::vector<std::string> arr; 


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> temp_char;
        arr.push_back(temp_char);
    }

    for (auto s : arr)
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At that point you might as well use `char temp_char[100]`. Also, what if someone enters a word that's longer than 99 characters?

Comment: Thats a valid point, but I assume OP is new in C++. More efficient way to use `std::streangstream` instead of `char *` or `std::string`, but this is unrelated for OP's question.

Comment: Better to use std::string and never ever use `new[]`.

Comment: The code in the question already uses `std::string` in the `std::vector`. Why would you show them how to introduce buffer overflows and memory leaks?

Comment: Well, if I put simly a `std::string` instrad of the allocation, OP might miss the real reason of the segmentation fault beacause of the implementation of the `std::string` hide it. But yes, mine is not a proper solution, more like show the conception behind the error.

Comment: I agree with @SPIFF that the OP want's to know about `char*` not working. You can't explain that by using a different type. Perhaps a comment to suggest a better approach (std::string) would be useful though.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char* temp_char;
> vector<string> arr; 
>
> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
> {
>     cin >> temp_char;
> }
> ```

Why the pointer?

What happens here is that you create a `char*` which points to an undefined location. `std::istream` (of which `std::cin` is an object) provides a special way to read input into a `char*`, which however works only when the target `char*` points to valid memory.

Otherwise, the **behaviour is undefined**, which means anything can happen, including crashes.

---

The solution is not use pointers but `std::getline`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore();

    std::vector<std::string> arr; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        arr.push_back(line);
    }
}
```